# Svelte on:dblclick doesnt work on a list row

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, svelte

I use Sveltestrap and need a double click handler for a row:

```
<ListGroupItem on:dblclick={handler(params)}>
  <Row>
    <Col><Icon name=........</Col>
       ...
  </Row>
</ListGroupItem>
```

When I add a Button below, `on:click` works as expected. I also checked that virtually any HTML component can have an on click / on double click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Components != DOM Elements.

You can only use events that are dispatched from the component or forwarded from within. `ListGroupItem` [does *not* forward `dblclick`](https://github.com/bestguy/sveltestrap/blob/4b2a88e9f16291d08a24a3df79a10c6397134ddc/src/ListGroupItem.svelte), only `click`.

As a workaround you can try adding a wrapper `div` with the event on it.

Note that all mouse actions should also be accessible via keyboard. Also, double click is a fairly uncommon gesture on the web, which may not be expected to exist by users.